# How to get String value from json_decode in php

Tags: php, json

My json-data is as follows -

```
[{"name": "ram"}]
```

**What I want is the value of `name` in a variable** e.g., `$fname`. I have tried -

```
<?php
$jsondata = '[{"name": "ram"}]';
//$obj = json_decode($jsondata);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
print_r($obj); // This line outputs as :- Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => ram ) ) 
//What I need is value of key
print_r($obj['name']);
foreach ($obj as $k=>$v){
echo $v;
}
?>
```

But I am unable to get desired output.

Comment: `print_r($obj);` And you will see the structure of your decoded json string. (Wait a minute and you will have tones of vampires here)

Comment: @Rizier123 it shows `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => ram ) ) ` using `print_r($obj)`, but I don't know how to use it, to get value of name

Comment: [`RTM`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: @Rizier123, I just read the manual. I think in layman language, it can be said that - output of my decoded json is Array inside an array. thanks for the link

Comment: ^ You got it! That's it! This is also why I let you look at the structure of the decoded json: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => ram ) )` <-- See 2x array! So it's multidimensional. And the first dimension is `0` then `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to get that value

```
<?php
$jsondata = '[{"name": "ram"}]';
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
//In case have multiple array
foreach ($obj as $k){
echo $k['name'];
}
//else
$obj[0]['name'];

//if 
$jsondata = '{"name": "ram"}';
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
//use 
echo $obj['name'];
?>
```

Comment: it works, but one question though, since my `json-data` contains only one `name`, wouldn't it be un-necessary to use `foreach`? if yes, then, what's the alternative for it? thanks.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari ^^ Look at the output again what your decoded json string prints! And read my manual link! (And that's why an answer should include an explanation)

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari if $jsondata = '{"name": "ram"}'; you can use $obj['name'] or you can use $obj[0]['name'] for your current jsondata

Answer (score 1):

As your output indicates, your JSON string represents an array containing one object. As you know that you want a value contained within the first element, you can get it directly:

```
$jsondata = '[{"name": "ram"}]';
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$name = $obj[0]['name'];
echo $name;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But @Call Sall VI has pointed out the same in his comment and modified the answer too accordingly (can't select 2 best answers), though I can upvote it :)