# PHP unable to get json object value

Tags: php, json

I am aware that this has been asked and answered, and I am looking at previous solutions

[How to get String value from json_decode in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449168/how-to-get-string-value-from-json-decode-in-php),
[PHP - cant get value with json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478022/php-cant-get-value-with-json-decode) and a couple of other questions.

I have a json object that is being returned from a cURL call,

```
$tokenInfo = GetToken();
echo $tokenInfo; // <-- this prints out the values as I would expect to see it (shown below)
$tokenJson = json_decode($tokenInfo); // <-- this does not seem to decode
echo 'Getting Token Info:';
echo $tokenJson['access_token']; // <-- this does not give me my access token
```

The resposne from my server to get my access token is as below

```
{"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":"bearer","expires_at":1626180544,"expires_in":86400,"refresh_token":"yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"}
```

I am trying to get the access token from this response, and anytime I try and get this value its coming back as false and I cant for the life of me figure out why.

I would appreciate any guidance you may have as I have not worked with PHP in a long time and thought that this should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: `json_decode` returns an object, so you'll probably need `echo $tokenJson->access_token`

Comment: A dupe for you to understand the difference between decoding to __object__ and to __array__.

Comment: you may want , sometime, to read the fabulous manual : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php